# Lua - I have a little problem with string.find

Tags: lua

I have a problem with my string.find, here is a code that works correctly:

```
local value = "268 956 30"

if value ~= nil then
    local _, _, a, b, c = string.find(value, '([%d%.]+) ([%d%.]+) ([%d%.]+)')

    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
end
```

> Return : 
>   268
>   956
>   30

When the variable contains the minus sign (-) then it returns a nil :

```
local value = "-268 -956 30"

if value ~= nil then
    local _, _, a, b, c = string.find(value, '([%d%.]+) ([%d%.]+) ([%d%.]+)')

    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
end
```

> Return :
>   nil
>   nil
>   nil

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust your pattern to allow for the `-`

Look at the result of your current code with this value `-268 956 30`

Output:

> 268
>
> 956
>
> 30

the result is the same as without the `-` on the first char this because the `-` is ignored as the pattern is not required to match the first char.

You can include the `-` in your pattern by adjusting your patter too

`(%-?[%d%.]+) (%-?[%d%.]+) (%-?[%d%.]+)`

Here we escape the `-` using `%` and then define how many we want to allow by using a `?` afterwords(matching 0 or 1 occurrences). This will allow the match to work for a valid number like `30` or `-30` but not `--30`, but as the pattern is still not anchored to the front of the string could still match `--30` for the first value but only returning `-30`. If this is undesired we can add `^` to the as the first char of the pattern.

Example:

```
local value = "-268 -956 30"

if value ~= nil then
    local _, _, a, b, c = string.find(value, '(%-?[%d%.]+) (%-?[%d%.]+) (%-?[%d%.]+)')

    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
end
```

Output:

> -268
>
> -956
>
> 30

---

Lua Pattern Resource: [FHUG: Understanding Lua Patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)

Comment: @Robostich
Note: If you're looking for sth. matching floating point numbers, the pattern `[%d%.]+` matches also `123.45.67`.